# JBoss basic access

Tags: ssh, solaris, localhost, access-control-list, jboss

I have JBoss 5 deployed on Solaris 10 - the servers connection has unrestricted high ports (>1023) open to the internet.

I can access the box via ssh & FTP from a second server on the same subnet and anywhere over the internet.

JBoss is running over port 8080 and is accessible via http://locahost:8080 on the box itself. I cannot access it via http://ip.add.goes.here:8080 from either the other server on the same subnet or via the internet.

Is there any service or configuration within JBoss or elsewhere on Solaris 10 that needs to be changed from default to allow http traffic to be served?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start JBoss binding to all IP addresses.

```
run.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: So I’m trying to start JBoss with the bind argument but want it to run in the background so it staying running after I kill the ssh session.
I’ve tried setting the ‘LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND’ environment variable to 1 before running ./run.sh but the process stays in the foreground, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Found this in another serverfault thread & it seems to work:
To get it to run after you exit: Start it with nohup, end it with &

I ran it as `nohup ./run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 &`.